# Highlight-to-show variables when using javascript debugger no longer working in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When using `debugger`, I used to be able to mouseover over a variable (or highlight a variable) and I'd get a tooltip that let me see the value of the variable. It has recently stopped working for me. Is this a setting somewhere? I don't recall disabling it.  How can I re-enable this? At the moment I need to use the Dev Tools console to print out the variables and it's annoying me.

Comment: It's a bug. Should be fixed in the next version. Use Chrome Canary meanwhile.

Comment: The guy above is right. I have been researching and there is not a primary solution.